# Custom login procedure on Windows(10)

Tags: authentication, windows-10, screen

Is there a way to create a custom login screen like Hello Windows, is there an api for such a thing?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can :

1. Search for “regedit” in your Start menu and launch it.
2. In the left-side panel, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Microsoft > Windows > Current Version > Policies > System.
3. In the right-hand panel, double-click “legalnoticecaption”.
4. In the “Value data” box, enter a title for your notice (for example, “ATTENTION” or “IF LOST, PLEASE CONTACT). Click OK.
5. Double-click “legalnoticetext”.
   Enter a message containing your contact info, like your name, email address or phone number. If you’re willing to provide a reward, mention that too. Click OK.

Comment: But will it provide an entry point for my app? I'd like to snap a webcam photo when the login screen appears.